# in sinatra :public is not returning a path as expected. bug or feature?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, public

In my app as part of my settings I

```
set :public, Proc.new { File.join(root, 'public') }
```

but if I look at the variable `public` in my config blocks, it's an Object that represents the whole app (or seems to)

```
public.to_json -->

{"extensions":[],"conditions":[],"routes":{},
 "inheritable_attributes":{},"errors":{},"prototype":null,"active_user":null,
 "templates":{},"filters":{"after":[],"before":[]},
 "middleware":[],"models_are_loaded":true}
```

but in my config block `public` used to just resolve to `'public'`

this is bugging me because each request to my app now complains that it "can't convert Class into String" for the line

```
set :images, Proc.new {File.join(public, 'images')}
```

but weirdly this used to work fine

Has something changed in Ruby or Sinatra in the last three weeks (I've been on holiday and this worked before I left)?

Note I've also tried just leaving the `set :public, ...` bit commented out as I used to do but that gives the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of sinatra 1.3, `public` has been deprecated in favor of `public_folder`. This was done to avoid overloading `Module#public`

It's now:

```
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
set :public_folder, "#{dir}/public"
```

I'm not sure why you are using a `Proc` though in your examples...

Comment: thanks. I just used `Proc` as that's how the various docs said to do it, and back then I knew very little Ruby.  And until now it's worked fine so thought to change it.  But yes I see I could optimise this app in a number of ways :-)

Comment: Yeah I imagine the `Proc` worked on older versions due how the settings were read. My guess is they've changed the settings handle code.